# Swift blur effect repeating on view change

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am using a blurViewEffect using the following code inside the `viewDidLoad()` function.
I am using Storyboard and Swift in the controller of the specific screen to achieve this.

```swift
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .clear
blurEffectView.frame = contenedorPaywall.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
contenedorPaywall.addSubview(blurEffectView)

blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) { [blurEffectView] in
    blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
```

It works perfectly for the structure I have, but the problem is that as soon as I change sections and come back it repeats the effect and everything gets blurrier.

**Example 1 First Blur**

[image: Normal blur]

**Example 2 After switching to a different section/page and then switching back to the same screen**

[image]

As you can see the second image is way blurrier. What I have noticed is that it seems to stop there. If I keep switching it stays the same level of blur as the second image, but I want to use the first one so more is visible below the text.

I tried re-running the blur code from zero, but I am not 100% sure how it works in this case. From what I understand it's more like an animation/transition.

How can I stop it from blurring more?

**UPDATE on cookednick's answer**

I changed the code to this because I wasn't sure where the startAnimation should go, but now it does the full blur instead. What am I doing wrong?

```swift
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .clear
blurEffectView.frame = contenedorPaywall.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
contenedorPaywall.addSubview(blurEffectView)

blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.185, curve: .linear) { [blurEffectView] in
    blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
        
blurAnimator.startAnimation()
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.185, repeats: false) { [blurAnimator] _ in
    if blurAnimator!.isRunning {
        blurAnimator!.stopAnimation(true)
        blurAnimator!.fractionComplete = 0.185
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What this looks like to me is a case where **Example 1** only exists because the UIViewPropertyAnimator fails to actually finish the first time it is run. You'll have to look at any code that starts/stops it. Use print statements or breakpoints to learn if they are called at times you do not expect. You can print the progress value of the animation, and if it's less than 1.0 when **Example 1** happens, there's your answer.

**Example 2** is the correct, full effect. This is also why you don't see it blur even further. This is because the progress of the animation has already reached 1.0 (100%) and cannot go further.

Edit:

If you would like to use the look of **Example 1** and never the look of **2**, you can do that with a timer.

When creating the animator:

```swift
// Use a duration of 1, double the intended length.
blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) { [blurEffectView] in
    blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
```

When starting the animation:

```swift
blurAnimator.startAnimation()
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { [blurAnimator] _ in
    // After 0.5 seconds have passed, we will manually stop the animator if it's still running.
    if blurAnimator.isRunning {
        blurAnimator.stopAnimation(true)
        blurAnimator.fractionComplete = 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to look as in Example 1, can't I stop it there?

Comment: Yes. Just double the animation length and start a `Timer` whenever you do the animation that lasts the actual length (0.5 seconds) to stop the UIViewPropertyAnimator at position 0.5. (50%)

Comment: Could you give me an example of that @cookednick? I am not really an expert on Swift so help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @MihailMinkov I edited my answer. I hope it goes well.

Comment: I added the example with your code to my question, but I think I did something wrong because now it always does the full blur. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MihailMinkov not easy to say without seeing your code

Comment: I added my code snippet to my question @cookednick it's the only place where I work with the blur effect. It's inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @MihailMinkov looks like there is not a good way to have the half-blur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but wanted to avoid adding a timer because it felt unreliable to me. But using the same "timing" idea, I simply stopped and finished the animator on the main queue after the initial `fractionComplete` has been added.

```swift
func setUpBlurView() {
    if (blurEffectView == nil) {
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
        blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .clear

        blurEffectView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        )
        presenter.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        
        blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3, curve: .linear) {
            [blurEffectView] in
            blurEffectView?.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        }
        blurAnimator.fractionComplete = 0.15

        presenter.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.blurAnimator?.stopAnimation(true)

            if let blurAnimator = self.blurAnimator, blurAnimator.state != .inactive {
                blurAnimator.finishAnimation(at: .current)
            }
        }
    }
}
```